# SemanticUI Form.Input type of email & tel have aria-invalid attribute added

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am updating a basic form where all inputs are of type "text", so that they have the correct `type` attributes set, when it's for an email, `type="email"`, and when it's for a phone number, `type="tel"`.

React Component:

```
    <Form.Input
      disabled={disabled ? true : false}
      id={field.name}
      placeholder={formattedName(field.name) || undefined}
      value={values[field.name]}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={showErrors ? validate : undefined}
      error={showErrors ? errors[field.name] : null}
      required={required || undefined}
      label={formattedName(field.name) || undefined}
      type="email"
    />
```

However, it seems the resulting HTML output is adding an `aria-invalid=true` attribute:

```
<div class="disabled required field">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <div class="ui disabled input">
    <input **aria-invalid="true"** placeholder="Email" required="" id="email" disabled="" type="email" tabindex="-1" value="plucks@gospotcheck.com">
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is SemanticUI doing this?  If I use the plain `<Input />` it's fine, but I'd rather not go this way.

Answer (score 0):

in 1 repo we have the above code for error: `error={showErrors ? errors[field.name] : null}`, which I copied over to the new repo.  However, it seems `null` is not making it happy, so I have changed to `error={showErrors ? errors[field.name] : undefined}`